# multiple css classes in selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want add a border to the bottom of the last element with the classes `onerow` and `light_grey_bg` (div c below).

I have the following html and css but it's not working as I expected. Is what I'm trying achievable?

html:

```
<div class="onerow">a</div>
<div class="onerow light_grey_bg">b</div>
<div class="onerow light_grey_bg">c</div>
<div class="onerow">d</div>
```

css:

```
.onerow.light_grey_bg {
  border-top: 1px solid #bdbfc2;
}
.onerow.light_grey_bg:last-of-type {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #bdbfc2;
    }
```

Comment: `last-of-type` works on just that, types (a.k.a. elements), not classes.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554552/why-does-classlast-of-type-not-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured it out:

```
.onerow.light_grey_bg {
  border-top: 1px solid #bdbfc2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdbfc2;
}
.onerow.light_grey_bg + .light_grey_bg {
  border-top: none;
}
```

This works for an unknown layout of divs too.

http://jsfiddle.net/f82bx/2/

Answer (score 2):

`:last-of-type` doesn't filter elements by their classes, but by their element type (like `div`, `a`, `p`, etc.) so your selector doesn't make sense, since it doesn't include any information about the type.

If your HTML remains the same, you can use the `+` selector to target the second instance:

```
.onerow.light_grey_bg + .onerow.light_grey_bg {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bdbfc2;
}
```

If there are more instances of this element, you can use as many `+` as needed to select the last one.

Comment: Can't he just use :last-child?

Comment: @michaelw90: No, because the last child (in his HTML) is not an instance of this element (with two classes). See: http://jsfiddle.net/xwA79/

Comment: @Hybrid I don't think I can use this solution because there's an unknown layout of "onerow" and "light_grey_bg" acccos the entire site

Comment: @Paul: In that case you'll have to use JS or jQuery.

Comment: I've figured it out, see my answer bellow :)

Comment: @Paul: Maybe I'm missing something but it doesn't seem to work in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f82bx/1/

Comment: @Hybrid: heres a little more css to show the the end result http://jsfiddle.net/f82bx/2/

Comment: @Paul: I see now. From your question I thought you were only interested in styling the last element with both classes.

Comment: @Hybrid: sorry the question wasn't clear enough. I have edited it now for future reading. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done in the way you suggested with CSS for the reason Hybrid stated.

Although....depending on what you're trying to accomplish... being sneaky is always an option

```
.light_grey_bg {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bdbfc2;
    margin-top:-1px;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f82bx/

It would depend on how many rows you have, their order etc... of course, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper(container) and define that the last child of the wrapper is the one you want to make the border

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="onerow">a</div>
<div class="onerow light_grey_bg">b</div>
<div class="onerow light_grey_bg">c</div>
<div class="onerow">d</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper .onerow:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdbfc2;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8fbUt/)**

Comment: This would put the line under 'd' but from the OP code he wants it under 'c' ?

Comment: I need the border on the last element that contains both "onerow" and "light_grey_bg" classes, so the border should appear under c

Comment: You are right, i change my code

Comment: I cant do that either because there's an unknown layout of "onerow" and "light_grey_bg" acccos the entire site

Comment: Just add one more  specific class to the wrapper and then give that specific class in the css like: .wrapper.mycustomcss .onerow:nth-child(3). This only affect the one you want.

Comment: I've figured it out, see my answer bellow :)