# Box-shadow not displaying and flex container not stretching

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm not sure if this is allowed, but my question can actually be splitted into two:

1. The bottom header should display a bottom box-shadow, but doesn't because of backgrounds and z-index (if I'm correct).
2. The `container` should occupy 100% of remaining available screen height. If the content in `container right` is longer, stretch both `container` and `container right`. `container left` should always be 100% remaining available height, stay on screen, and display a scrollbar if the content is too long for the container.

As you can see in the situation screenshot below, currently I'm not able to do either.

How can I fix both of these issues? I've been messing around trying various solutions, but none of them seem to work 100%.

---

Do note that there's a certain layering order:

Container > Header(s) + Footer > Sidepanel > Modal

---

Here's the situation: [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/PieterVDE/pen/zRzyxg?editors=1100)

*I've only included the relevant code here for the sake of brevity.*

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header-box-shadow">Header 1</div>
<div class="header-box-shadow">Header 2</div>
<div class="header-box-shadow">Header 3</div>
<div class="header-box-shadow">Header 4</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left">container left</div>
    <div class="right">container right</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>

<div class="sidepanel">sidepanel</div>
<div class="modal">modal</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.header-box-shadow {
  &:last-of-type {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100000;
  }
}

.container {     
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 

  .content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;

    .left {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .right {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
  }
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.sidepanel {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[image: current situation]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please update so, that we can understand better.

Comment: Tried to make my problem(s) more clear @AniruddhAgarwal, does it help?

Comment: I decided to delete my answer after some more thoughts. As the fixed positioned `footer` and `sidepanel` appears to have dynamic height/width, you will need a script to make those play along with your Flexbox layout. If their height/width can be set, a CSS solution will be available.

Comment: Based on a comment in an answer below I assume you want a sticky `footer`, correct? ... and if you explain how the `sidepanel` relates to the rest, I will post a proper answer.

Comment: Yes, the footer is indeed sticky. The sidepanel is a slidein, so the only requirement is that it appears above everything except the modal when called. For positioning etc, that's already taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your complete HTML layout inside another div, which you give `display: flex`. You can then give this div, let's call it `.outer`, 100% viewport height. Then, on the container, set `flex: 1;` - this will make sure that the container stretches and fills remaining vertical space. You can then also remove the footers fixed position. Next, set `overflow-y: scroll;` on the left container side. It will scroll when the content gets too large.

For your box shadow, `:last-of-type` will not work, because the last `div` is not the last of it's type in the parent container. Therefore, add a class `.last` to the last header item and apply the box shadow to that selector.

Have a demo here: https://codepen.io/NikxDa/pen/vdZbxV?editors=1100

Please let me know if this is the result you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Your solution is close, thank you very much for the work so far. However; footer should still be at the bottom of the page if `container right` has content which is longer than 100%/100vh.

Comment: I think that is not doable with flexbox. You could try using CSS Grid.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is I think that `last-of-type` selector only works on node-selectors like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13554698/5859685) is described.

After compiling your scss there is `.header-box-shadow:last-of-type {` and because of the class it doesn't work.

So if you make an extra class for the element with the shadow, it will work.

```
.hasShadow{
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```