# How to get the last element of specific class or attribute without using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, queryselector

Cannot get the last element with specific class or attribute using querySelector.

My Current Code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="abc" db="box"></div>
    <div class="abc" db="box"></div>
    <div class="abc" db="box"></div>
    <div class="def"></div>
    <div class="abc" db="box"></div>
    <div class="ghi"></div>
    <div class="abc" db="box"></div>
    <div class="ghi"></div>
    <div class="ghi"></div>
</div>
<script>
    console.log(document.querySelector('#wrapper>[db="box"]:last-child')); // showing null
    console.log(document.querySelector('#wrapper>div.abc:last-child')); // showing null
</script>
```

I've found some solutions like:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper>div.abc');
console.log(elements[elements.length - 1]);
```

The above code works but it gets all of the elements first and then retrieves the last one from it.

```
document.querySelector('#wrapper>[db="box"]:last-child')
```

If anyone could make the above query correct then it will search for the last one only.

Comment: last child is only if it is the last element....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/how-can-i-select-the-last-element-with-a-specific-class-not-last-child-inside-o

Comment: The `length - 1` solution you've listed is fine, why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Not possible using CSS native selectors. Just bite the bullet and select 'em all. Your next line of thinking will be, ooh, what about `:last-of-type`? That won't work either, for reasons yonder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554552/why-does-classlast-of-type-not-work-as-i-expect

Comment: @Leland I've already tried the `:last-of-type` bro! but I forgot to mention it in the question.

Comment: @Leland Can you explain why it's not possible or can you refer me a link?

Comment: I already have :) Read the answers in that link - "there is no selector for the last instance of a class"

Comment: @DBS I had already provided the reason in the question **If anyone could make the above query correct then it will search for the last one only.**

Comment: That doesn't explain **why** you don't want to use it, but I assume what you are implying is that you think it will affect performance? If that is the case, you probably don't need to worry about it, it's very unlikely there will be any measurable performance impact from that approach.

Answer (score 1):

If CSS selectors are not powerful enough for your requirement, consider using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expressions like in this example:

```js
console.log(
  document.evaluate(`//*[@id='wrapper']
    /*[@db='box' and
    not(following-sibling::*/@db='box')]`,
    document, () => {},
    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE
  ).singleNodeValue
);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="abc" db="box"></div>
  <div class="abc" db="box"></div>
  <div class="abc" db="box"></div>
  <div class="def"></div>
  <div class="abc" db="box"></div>
  <div class="ghi"></div>
  <div class="abc" db="box"></div>
  <div class="ghi"></div>
  <div class="ghi"></div>
</div>
```

Only the last matching element is selected, all earlier ones are ruled out by the condition `not(following-sibling::*/@db='box')]`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Don't you think that it's more resource intensive than the `elements[elements.length -1]` method.

Comment: I cannot answer that. But I expect no big effect.